# What is wrong with this except statement? Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, except

Code works until I try to handle the ValueError with an except statement.  Returns an invalid syntax traceback.

```
def write():
    filename = input('Please Enter the File name:') + '.txt';
    with open (filename, "a") as f:
        while True:
            a,b = input('Enter in format Name,Carbs per 10 grams').split(',')
            a = str (a)
            b1 = float (b)
            f.write (a+','+ b+ '\n');
            except ValueError:
                continue
            loop = input ('Do you want to add anything else y/n:')
            if loop == 'n':
                break
```

Comment: your indentation is off, can you fix that to match your code

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a `try` statement in your code.  You probably want something like this.  See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) for more examples.

```
while True:
    try:
        a,b = input('Enter in format Name,Carbs per 10 grams').split(',')
        a = str (a)
        b1 = float (b)
        f.write (a+','+ b+ '\n');
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

Comment: Yep that was it.  I believe I removed the try statement in order to test something and forgot to re-add when I had my except statement added.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a try statement to have an except statement.

```
def write():

    filename = input('Please Enter the File name:') + '.txt';
    with open (filename, "a") as f:
        while True:
            try:     #added try statement
                a,b = input('Enter in format Name,Carbs per 10 grams').split(',')
                a = str (a)
                b1 = float (b)
                f.write (a+','+ b+ '\n');
            except ValueError:
                continue
            loop = input ('Do you want to add anything else y/n:')
            if loop == 'n':
                break
```

Comment: Did this fix you problem? If so, I would appreciate if you accept my answer. Thanks.